# Good Source Control Hosting For Privacy?

Tags: version-control

I'm looking for a very private source control/hosting solution.  Short of hosting my own, and seeing as I'm the only collaborator, what is a good service for this?

I'm using Git.  The most important aspect is privacy. I don't want anyone to see my code, I'm simply using it for source control/backup. I will be the only developer.

Comment: If you're using git, your repository is on your computer - just back it up like any other directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Virtual Private Servers

You haven't mentioned the budget so I'm going to assume that it's not that important for you. We have all of our source code on **virtual servers hosted** by [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) (you could pick any other VPS provider) and we **access them over ssh**. The big advantages:

(a) Private - you need ssh to access the box

(b) Accessible anywhere there's a network connection

(c) Nightly & weekly Backups are included for free

I'm a fan of Slicehost (been using them for over two years now) but you could set up the same system with any VPS provider. There's **and article on setting up git on Slicehost** [here](http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/5/13/capistrano-series-setting-up-git)